# In Jekyll: Want to use category (or tag) name in a list, but not all posts in a category

Tags: jekyll

I want to create a category index that simply creates a list of the categories in the site and a link to each category's index, as generated by the category index generator.

```
---
layout: default
title: "Categories"
---

<div id="category-index" class="container">
  <ul id="categories">
    {% for category in site.categories %}
    <li><a href="/{{category}}/">{{ category }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

but this give the entire array of posts. I just want the category name. I've tried `category.key`, `category.name`, and `category.title`, but I just do not seem to be able to get just that name.

I am also hoping to do the same with site.tags, assuming there is a similar answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking at the correct `site.categories`, but for the name, you must reference the first object in the array as `category[0]`.

Regarding tag lists, you may want to look at this [helper class](http://xerial.org/helpers/tags-list.html).

#### UPDATE:

A more elegant way to code this, using the Liquid templating engine's filter, would be:

```
{% for category in site.categories %}
    {{ category | first }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sadly, the link through the helper class page to the github repo is throwing a 404.

Comment: I think [this](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/api/bootstrap-api.html) is the link they were hoping to put there.